# Can I continue communication after Java host drop

Tags: java, networking

I've created a java client and server application in order to facilitate a multiplayer game.  It runs fine, but I'm trying to make my code more robust.

If the host quits the game, or for some reason the game on the host's machine crashes, then everyone else will be disconnected - making the game a waste.

Is there a way to deal with a dropped game host so that the game can continue running on another player's machine?

My initial thought is give each player all the connection information for every other player and designate a second person to host the game if the current host should fail.

Is there a better way to do this or am I on the right track?

Comment: Having a dedicated host would be a good start.

Comment: The multiplayer isn't extensive enough to warrant playing it over a dedicated server.  It will be able to be hosted on a player's machine, and I'm looking to know how to switch the game to another player's machine if the one hosting the game get dropped for some reason.

Comment: I can only think of one solution. All clients know about other clients. When host fails, everybody stops and try to communicate to the first one on the list.

Comment: Can you have multiple servers running on different hosts? This is similar to bittorrent (multiple trackers) or skype (multiple supernodes).

Comment: I could have each player hosting a game at all times, but that seems a little excessive.  It's not an mmo, it has a max of 4 players.

Comment: Tuff question. It depends on your game architecture. If only a packet retransmission is required, you can use UDP Broadcasts and eliminate the server interly, after the game has started. You will have to provide more information about the architecture of your network and the transmitted game data to get a quialified answer.